# Scala Jar packaged by sbt assembly doesn't read relative path of file but same works in intelliJ

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I came across this interesting problem in scala sbt. Any help will be very much appreciated.

I read the file as follows

```
 CSVReader.open(new File(getClass.getResource("/sampleData/sample.csv").getPath))
 CSVReader.open(new File("src/main/resources/sampleData/sample.csv"))
```

This works perfectly in intellij but it doesn't work in jar

In Intellij it doesnt read file for the following

```
CSVReader.open(new File(getClass.getResource("/sampleData/sample.csv").getPath))
```

> file is present inside src/main/resources/

But this doesn't work when assemble it using

```
sbt cleam assemble
```

and then try giving

```
java java -jar /Users/sample/target/scala-2.11/Sample-assembly-1.0.jar
```

Then I get following exeception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/sample/target/scala-2.11/Sample-assembly-1.0.jar!/sampleData/sample.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a file from the resources folder, use following code:

```
val reader =CSVReader.open(scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/sample.csv")))
println(reader.all())
```

I used this [CSVReader library](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv).